# Go closure with naked return

Tags: go, closures

I am playing around with Go and am trying to implement a `fibonacci` function that returns a closure that returns fibonacci numbers. The problem can be found in the go tool tour. Here is a closure implementation that uses a regular (non-naked) return:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    a := 0
    b := 1
    return func() int {
        t := a + b
        a = b
        b = t
        return b
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

The function correctly returns the following:

```
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
```

I tried writing the `fibonacci` function differently by trying to use a naked return within the closure function, but it produces an error:

> ./compile20.go:9:7: b declared and not used

Here is the code that generates the error

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    a := 0
    b := 1
    return func() (b int) {
        t := a + b
        a = b
        b = t
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Anybody know how the variable `b` is not being used? `b` is obviously used in the first line of the closure function (`t := a + b`).

Comment: parameter `b int` is shadowing local variable `b := 1`, that's why *b* is never used in `func fibonacci()`

Comment: tip: you can use multiple assignment to make your code simpler: `a, b = b, a+b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables defined in the return segment shadow the variable with the same name in the outer scope. Inside your returned function, `b` refers to the one defined in the return value.

You can remove the first declaration (and initialization) of `b` and the program passes the check, although the logic is not right.

```
// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    a := 0
    b := 1 // declare a variable b and initialize with 1
    return func() (b int) { // declare a variable b with default initialization
        t := a + b // b refers to the variable defined in the return value
        a = b
        b = t
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Didn't know that named return parameters couldn't be defined outside the function